# Using SL API can't get the storage IP of the disk

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

```
curl "https://711197_bxadm%40us.ibm.com:<key>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/6640135/getObject.json?objectMask=serviceResourceBackendIpAddress"
{}
```

We can't get the storage IP of the disk. You can easily recreate the issue with this command.

Code to attach the disk -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-softlayer-cpi-release/blob/master/src/bosh-softlayer-cpi/softlayer/vm/softlayer_virtual_guest.go#L230

Answer (score 0):

For me the request is working fine, this might be an issue with your storage disk I recommend you to submit a ticket in softlayer in order they take a look at the device.